# Mailing a tar.gz file

Tags: email

How would I use the mail command, without the mutt utility, to send a tar.gz file. 
The Mail utility works on the command line, however it asks me who to cc and the text on the terminal page. It also requires me to ctr D to send a mail. How would I avoid this in a script?

Answer (score 2):

This question has sort of been answered already...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line

Based on the answers I've seen above though it doesn't deal with the CC part though. Basically, you just need to add a "-c ccaddress@emailaddress.com" option.

```
cat message.txt | mail -s "Backup" -a file.tar.gz backup@email.com -c ccaddress@emailaddress.com
```

Stick it in a script file and it that will be the basis for further automation.

Comment: I may be reading the question wrong, but it sounds like they don't want to fill out the CC field at all.

Answer (score 1):

You cat some sort of message file to the mail utility.

```
cat mailbody.txt | mail -A yourfile.tgz -s "your mail subj line" email@to.send.to
```

Note that contrary to previous answer at least in Ubuntu mail utility you specify attachments by -A. -a is used to add extra headers.